# dnsmasq dns nameserver priority parameters - strict-order

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I have a setup specifying two DNS namservers.  One in local, the other is external.  The local one is a *pihole*, which itself forwards requests externally after url filtering.  The external one is set in case the *pihole* device software or hardware fails.

The *pihole* response time is about 20 ms, the external response time is about 2 ms.  Although the *pihole* is listed as a nameserver before the external, *dnsmasq* will by default test timing responses and use whichever is faster.

*dnsmasq* does however offer a parameter `strict-order` which should use the nameservers in the strict order they are listed, and so in this case should only use the external nameserver if the *pihole* "fails".

In practice using the parameter `strict-order` doesn't work as hoped, and the external nameserver still wins.  The [dnsmasq manual page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) doesn't go into detail about the definition of "failed".

**I am looking for other parameter setting which might solve this problem.**

As a last resort I would use an external program to detect *pihole* working order, and manipulate the *dnsmasq* nameserver settings accordingly.  But that is not a preferred solution.

Comment: Alternate DNS servers with different views of the world where never a kosher solution, and if I am not wrong, the situation is the same with dnsmask. You should use the pihole for solving all the DNS requests.

Comment: The secondary is for backup if the pihole really fails.  For example, a software bug crashes the software (entirely possible), or if the hardware fails (less likely).

Comment: The secondary is for backup if the pihole really fails.  For example, a software bug crashes the software (entirely possible), or if the hardware fails (less likely).  *** A backup is necessary for others who need immediate continued internet access in case of pihole software or hardware failure  *** If you consider the problem closely, it is actually asking to divide the duty of the two servers cleanly, exactly so that "dueling servers" does not happen.

Comment: And that is what I am saying all along. You are having problems because that is a bad idea from the implementation point of view. What you are asking from the implementation point of view is not advisable to do.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro -  The Pihole needs to be used, but if the Pihole fails the system must continue to work seamlessly.  There are other people needing to use that system who can't immediately fix it if it is broken if I am not there.
Start from the requirements and figure out the implementation to achieve that.
Don't you agree?

Comment: I would never use an rpi on essential critical mission systems of this kind. I am just saying counting on defining master/slave DNS systems or something similar does not work, even as a redundancy. You need two piholes, a clustering system or something similar that points you to the pilhole and 8.8.8.8 or something similar.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - I followed you up to "two piholes".  The rest exceeds by present knowledge but I'd like to understand it - what do you mean by "clustering system"?  And how does "pihole and 8.8.8.8" differ from the pihole and 8.8.8.8 (external DNS) I am using now?  I expec this will get moved to chat - be prepared.

Comment: I see we are getting out of your comfort zone, sorry about it. Just get the notion that using a pihole and an alternate DNS as secondary external DNS is bound to fail and will let you down when the pihole goes down.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I too wanted to accomplish this. I have a router running dnsmasq and a PiHole. Raspberry Pi SD cards are prone to failure, so when DNS goes down, the internet is effectively down for everyone in my house who is not a sysadmin. I'm afraid the comments worried about a mission-critical situation are missing the forest for the trees.

I found that the `strict-order` setting does work, but the docs are vague on the fact that they [need to be specified in reverse order](https://community.ui.com/questions/DNS-forwarding-Dnsmasqs-strict-order-option-ignored/ef5e9a3c-e0d5-4e0e-992f-deb8888a40f9) in your configuration. Counter-intuitive, and I wish the docs would spell this out.

```
no-resolv
strict-order # NOTE: List servers in reverse order below (bottom is highest priority)
server=45.90.30.131 # NextDNS 2
server=45.90.28.131 # NextDNS 1
server=192.168.1.2 # PiHole
```

I tested this at home, and 192.168.1.2 is receiving all my DNS requests. I stopped the PiHole server to verify that requests would be forwarded to the other servers I specify. While it does work, they are very slow to resolve because the router is trying the servers in order with every request. I tried to figure out how to reduce dnsmasq's timeout, but [apparently that doesn't exist as a setting](https://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2013q2/007102.html). dnsmasq's creator Simon Kelley says:

> The upstream timeout for dnsmasq is always identical to the client's
> timeout, so the only way to do this is to reduce the timeouts at the
> client end.
>
> However, if you can arrange that packets sent to 10.2.1.2 return a "No
> route to host" error when it's not up, things will fail much quicker.
> That may be possible by arp table or routing table manipulation, I've
> not looked at the details.

I tried shutting down the PiHole instead of just stopping the DNS server to see if the requests will fail more quickly, but didn't see any change. I assume there's no automated way to handle this, but it would be great if someone could chime in on some router config that would speed this up.

Comment: Very helpful information!  It does seem like a difficult problem.  If dnsmasq would allow a plugin for that problem it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, dnsmasq will try all request with one server until query timeout, and use second server as fallback. There's an upper bound of how long one server could be used. defined in `config.h`.

```
#define FORWARD_TEST 1000 /* try all servers every 1000 queries */
#define FORWARD_TIME 600 /* or 10 minutes */
```

taken from [Pihole-FTL Github repo](https://github.com/pi-hole/FTL/blob/fb9b2744b411cc1a04527b909675447fdab8a471/src/dnsmasq/config.h#L27-L28) (a fork of dnsmasq with AD blocking).

search for `OPT_ORDER` in the repo for implementation detail.

Comment: I'm not actually talking about the dnsmasq in Pihole, but rather the one on my box, which points first to Pihole, then to a secondary DNS server.  If the Pihole fails, then I won't be using the Pihole dnsmasq.  But thanks for trying.